# Incorrect String Length in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, data-annotations

I'm using EF6 (Code First) in a project.

By having below class:

```
public class State
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

I expect to have `Code` as `nvarchar(10)` in database but I get `nvarchar(3)`. I see the correct length for `Name` column but can't figure out why `Code` is not created correctly.

Edit:
I have the Country class as below:

```
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string Code { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I think, EF thinks the Code in State class is the Code in Country class as there is association between them.

Now, question is how should I tell EF that the Code in State class is not the Foreign Key to Country class?

Comment: what you're using, database first or code?

Comment: I'm using Code First

Comment: So, what is the problem, is it giving an error or exception or just generates code incorrectly?

Comment: There is no error. Database creates w/o any error. Only the column length is nor correct.

Comment: Is there any convention added by you in configuration?

Comment: what do you mean of Configuration? if you mean the OnModelCreating, No I'm not using anything related to this entity.

Comment: did you check the migration code ? maybe something went wrong before updating the database

Comment: @CyberProgs, Migration is not involved as this happens on the first db creation. please see my update on question and let me know the solution.

Comment: since you are referring to country class it will create a column that connect two tables , even if you change the name of code property it will create additional column like country_code

Comment: @CyberProgs, I think that is the problem, but is there any other way than changing the property names? for example, can I tell EF that use a different field name as foreign key?

Comment: What's the name of the foreign key field (to Country) in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even after working with it for a long time, EF is still surprising me. Until now I was thinking that by default EF is searching for property named `{Navigation Property Name}{Referenced Entity PK Property Name}` as default explicit FK property. But with your sample (verified), seems like it also does the same for property named `{Referenced Entity PK Property Name}`.

Since `ForeignKey` attribute cannot be used to specify the *table column* name (it can only specify FK/navigation *property* name), if you want to keep the model classes exactly as they are, you should use the `MapKey` fluent configuration, for instance:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<State>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.Country)
    .WithMany(s => s.States)
    .Map(s => s.MapKey("CountryCode"));
```

Comment: I came to the same surprising conclusion and also found out that including a property `CountryCode` in `State` makes EF infer the association correctly again (if `CountryCode` is the actual FK field name, of course). It's more versatile than we thought :)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'll try it tonight and will keep you updated.

Comment: This looks like a solution with a minor change in your code. I update your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`MaxLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute(v=vs.103).aspx) instead, EF will decide how large to make a string value field when it creates the database.

[`StringLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.aspx) is data annotation, that will used to validate user input.

MSDN:

> **MaxLength** - Specifies the maximum length of array or string data allowed in a property.
>
> **StringLength** - Specifies the minimum and maximum length of characters that are allowed in a data field.

### Since Question Updated:

Use `[ForeignKey("CountryCode")]` atribute, change your `Code` in `Country` class to `CountryCode` (or whatever you prefer) and specify your column name by `Column["Code"]` attribute:

```
public class State
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("CountryCode")]
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(3)]
    [Column["Code"]]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

MSDN Links: [Column Attribute](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/column-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx), [ForeignKey Attribute](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Or just change your `Code`s to `StateCode` and `CountryCode` and use `[ForeignKey("CountryCode")]` attribute.

Comment: I used [MaxLength(10)] but no change!!

Comment: I think I found the reason. I update my question and please let me know what should I do.

Comment: @FLICKER Actually here is no need for `MaxLength`, because StringLength also infers the string field size. But someone was saying that, there is some differences in codefirst.

Comment: yeap, you don't have any relations created between them, right?

Comment: Actually State should refer to Country but no on State.Code. I know the similarity of the property names makes EF to confuse but is there any way to correct the issue w/o changing the property names?

Comment: put `[ForeignKey("Code")] ` attribute to your `Country` property in `State` class. If it helps, let me know, I will update my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157965/discussion-between-sem--and-flicker).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are referring to another class in the `State model` it will create a foreign key for you based on the name of the properties , so to avoid making the `EF` decide what the name of the column for you add the following in the state class :

```
public string CountryId { get; set; }
```

if you want to choose another name other than `CountryId` , suppose you want to change it to `CountryForeignKey` you can use the following:

```
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
.
.
.
[ForeignKey("CountryForeignKey")]
        public Country Country { get; set; }

        public string CountryForeignKey { get; set; }
```

and this is what you get in the database 
[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'll check the other answer and will chose the one which is better fit for me.